# No response from web service on localhost

Tags: web-services, wsdl, localhost, nusoap

I'm using NuSOAP and PHP to connect to a web service (WSDL) and I can't get any response or error while trying locally. Once I move it to our server everything works fine, but I'm not sure what I need to configure locally to get things rolling.

I'm using WAMP on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the web service required SSL connection and WAMP doesn't support SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get an error because your PHP.INI is probably hide setup to hide the errors.

Put in your php.ini:

```
display_errors = on
```

restart your WAMP server and try again.

Comment: You can try see the log. Normally errors within Wamp are revelead in the log. The log folder is under the WAMP folder.

Comment: You can try the windows event viewer. The last shot I have.